# Is it possible to create desktop / other Windows shortcuts that invoke media keys / volume controls?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, shortcuts

Basically- I do have dedicated media keys on my keyboard but they are touch-sensitive and quite high on my keyboard (often covered by my desk when the kb tray isn't fully out). With Win8 it's possible to use a media key or kb volume key to display a "now playing" toast with media keys on it- but I was wondering if it would be possible to invoke this with a windows shortcut- something I could stick on my taskbar (creating my own media toolbar for e.g.) or on my desktop to invoke the toast and control my media without relying on the keyboard button.

Is there a windows command to invoke keypresses at all, and can this be set to media keys?

Comment: What media player are you using? Are the toast notifications associated with Windows Media Player?

Comment: They're part of Windows 8 / WinRT's audio platform. They control whichever WinRT app is currently playing audio. It's more about asking if it's possible to invoke keyboard media keys with windows shortcuts, and less about the toast display.

Comment: Special media keys are generally hard-coded and difficult to trigger. If there's a scancode that can be identified then maybe something like AutoHotkey can help. My point was that perhaps we can tackle the problem from the opposite direction. If we can figure out how to trigger the same actions as the media keys (play, pause etc.) directly using the media player, wouldn't that solve your problem as well?